# What address IP is argument for InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Lets consider following call: `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()`.

What address IP is argument for this call? We know that it is reverse DNS query, however we don't know what address IP is resolved to DNS name.
Moreover, is it possible to invoke ***equivalent*** function in python/bash/commandline tool (I would like to check what this function returns without installing JAVA).